# How to retrieve XML file content in a method based on some parameter passed to that method?

Tags: c#, xml

Here is the method in which I am trying to get the XML file contents based on a parameter passed to that method. I am getting an exception in `if` condition

> NullReference: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Code:

```
public void restoreClientReceipt(string piClientName)
{
      doc.Load(@"C:\Users\riyazahamed.angadi\Desktop\DeveloperAssignment\TestProject\Receipt.xml");
      XmlNodeList allItems = doc.SelectNodes("/Receipt/clientName/Items");

      foreach (XmlNode node in allItems)
      {
           if (node["clientName"].Attributes["NameOfClient"].Value == piClientName)
           {
               List<string> listOfSavedItems = new List<string>();
               string str = node.Attributes["Name"].Value;
               listOfSavedItems.Add(str);
               Console.WriteLine(node["Items"]);
           }
      }
}
```

And this is my XML file from which I want to get all the succeeding element values within my parent node `<clientName>  <clientName/>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Receipt>
    <clientName NameOfClient="SAM">
        <Items Name="Milk, Low fat, 1Liter(11.2each)(4) 44.8" />
        <Items Name="Fish, Salmon (14each)(2) 28" />
        <Items Name="Sum 72.8" />
    </clientName>
</Receipt>
```

Second question is: I have DLL named OfferTest.dll in my project but it doesnt have source code.

Requirement is that I have to dynamically load the DLL and check for classes that is implementing one of interface; the interface is shown below.

```
 public interface IOffer
{
 bool checkForOffer(string piName, int piCount, double piPrize, out double  poDiscount);
     bool checkForOffer(string piName, double piWeight, double piPrize, out double poDiscount);
}
```

Maybe from DLL I have to find class (from DLL) which is implementing this interface and the methods defined in it.

I have zero knowledge of loading DLLs dynamically.

Comment: at which line? show screenshot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please work hard on your presentation. 1st: split it into two questions. 2nd remove everything not necessary. 3rd replace everything with generic terms, such that the question is relevant to a broader audience. 4th make sure to use proper spelling.

Comment: The preferred format for questions on StackOverflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).  Please split the 2nd issue out into a new post.

Comment: Using the XPath expression `/Receipt/clientName/Items` will return to you the `<Items />` nodes, none of which have a `clientName` descendant or a `NameOfClient` attribute

Comment: so is there any way to get them? kindly suggest me some solution.i want to get all items based on the "piclientname" parameter.

Comment: or if i have an xml like this without "Nameofclient" attribute..can i get them?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Receipt>
    <clientName  SAM>
   
    </clientName>
</Receipt>

Comment: @Muhammad saqlain : I am getting exception in if condition............... ........  if (node["clientName"].Attributes["NameOfClient"].Value == piClientName).        is there any better way of getting al those vaues based on that parameter?

Answer (score 0):

> I have dll named OfferTest.dll in my project but it doesnt have source
>   code .
>
> requirement is that i hve to dyanamically load the dll and check for
>   classes that is implementing IOffer

```
var type = typeof(IOffer);
var types = Assembly.LoadFile("PathToYourAssembly").GetTypes()
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

Comment: i want to check for the classes in the Dll and the methods .how do i  do that?